# Better way to check Nullability of deep level Object reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
public class A
{
    public B obj{get; set;}
    public A()
    {
        obj=new B();
    }
}
public class B
{
    public C obj{get; set;}
    public B()
    {
        obj=new C();
    }
}
public class C
{
    public D obj{get; set;}
    public C()
    {
        //obj=null;
        obj=new D();
    }
}
public class D
{
    public string s{get;set;}
    public D()
    {
        //s="Some string";
        s=null;
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A testObject = new A();
        if(testObject!=null && testObject.obj!=null && testObject.obj.obj!=null && testObject.obj.obj.obj!=null && testObject.obj.obj.obj.s !=null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String is not null");
            return;
        }

        //This will obviously fails if any of the object of A,B,C,D class is null
        //if(testObject.obj.obj.obj.s !=null)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("String is not null");
        //    return;
        //}

        Console.WriteLine("String is NULL");
        return;
    }
}
```

There exists 4 Classes (A,B,C,D) in Example having chained reference.
I just want to know if there exists better option to check for nullability then the one I used in this Example?
(I want to access string variable 's' from object of class A, so in between if any object is null, an exception is thrown. I want to know if there is better way as this will get worse if there are more deep levels of references , though they are not much recommended but what if it exists.)

http://rextester.com/CGUU62557
(PS:I read some answers , solving this by REFLECTION but that doesn't helps with generic collections.)

Comment: Law of Demeter? What could it hurt?

Comment: @user6144226 no it won't ,it will be best to keep it in mind always , but there are situations to deal with.
and this is one here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `equals`:

```
if(!testObject.equals(null))
{
  //your logic
}
```

And a better way is to use `ReferenceEquals`:

```
    if(Object.ReferenceEquals(null, testObject))
    {
       //your logic
    }
```

The ReferenceEquals will return true if your object is null.

Comment: It will check for nullability of testObject, not the objects it consists.
This will surely fail.

Comment: Object.ReferenceEquals(null, testObject.obj.obj) will check for the nested object. You cannot check nullability for your nested object implicitly.

Comment: @Barr_J Thanks , I wonder how I missed this one , thats some cool way to do this, (at least a one liner).

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

`testObject!=null && testObject.obj!=null && testObject.obj.obj!=null && testObject.obj.obj.obj!=null` etc.

can be rewritten as

`testObject?.obj?.obj?.obj?.obj != null`

But I would say to be referencing that many layers deep into an object and its properties has "code smell" warning attached to it. It means your code is coupled to the deep internals of your objects, which if they only represent plain data, may not be an issue, but if they represent complex behaviour is probably something you want to avoid.

Comment: Yes that is just as rewrite as you said.
I just want to know if there exists some super smart way to do this.

Comment: "Super smart" is a pretty subjective judgement. You'd have to post a sample of what you think it might look like.

Comment: Duhh, if I would have idea about some smart way then I must not have asked question here. Think bro.
Thats why we ask in Community for better solutions.

Comment: Wow, and that's how you're not going get them. I didn't suggest you post the answer, just an example of what sort of thing "you think it might look like".

Comment: IRONY is , I already got one. Sir,you can't get anywhere with this attitude.
and for your information , I already mentioned some hint "REFLECTION" and that is kinda smart to use.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you want, but you can use the `Null-Conditional Operator`

```
if(A?.B?.C?.D == null)
{
   //Something was null
}
```

Comment: SIr, you sure it will work? Using class names for checking nullability? (OBJECTS ..)

Comment: No not the class name, just instantiated objects.

Answer (score 0):

Test it by making it null.

```
testObject.obj = null;
```

This will not throw any exception

```
if (testObject?.obj?.obj?.obj?.s != null)
```

This statement `testObject?.obj?.obj?.obj?.s` return `null` as a result

Comment: Thats the same thing as I wrote, using null propagation is just a rewrite.
All I want to know is if there exists some SMART way to do this.

Comment: @Deepanshu There is. Rethink the way you build your objects. Do you really have to go through 4 objects to get what you need?

Comment: All the answers you wrote, will work but are not smart. This will make the code much more complicated when  further objects are dealt with. Use the tools you have to make things work and in the same time maintainable. the equals method will do just the same and the ReferenceEquals will work perfectly on nested objects. that's just it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by using `Reflection` dynamically;

```
    private static bool CheckPropertiesAsNullRecursively(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        var objType = obj.GetType();
        if (objType.IsPrimitive || objType == typeof(Decimal) || objType == typeof(String) || objType == typeof(Double))//You should compare the primitive types to determine them
        {
            return false;
        }
        var properties = objType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            if (CheckPropertiesAsNullRecursively(objType.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).GetValue(obj)))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Usage**;

```
var val = CheckPropertiesAsNullRecursively(testObject);//If it returns true, at least one property should be null
```

Comment: Great, was waiting for code like this.
I will check it and mark answer as accepted.
Its what I expected.

Comment: Except  a) it can recurse forever if you have a loop in your object references b) it unnecessarily fetches properties by name when it already has the propertyInfo required c) I can't think of any circumstances at all where it would be useful to know that some property of some property of some property of some property of an object happens to be null without knowing which one it is.  But well done to Rainman for reading your mind.